# Micronaut how to build both fatjar and war like Spring Boot or Grails?

Tags: gradle, micronaut

Is there any way to build both war and fatjar in micronaut? Just like Spring Boot or Grails ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the documentation:

- JAR: https://docs.micronaut.io/1.3.7/guide/index.html#deployingApp

> create a runnable JAR file by running `./gradlew assemble`

As for WAR, there is separate documentation aside from the user guide:

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-servlet/latest/guide/#warDeployment

Comment: Thanks. I've checked this document already. But is there any way build fatjar and war without change `build.gradle` ? Like spring boot or grails. Seems this can only build fatjar or war in one time, if I want to build another, I have to change `build.gradle` to modify dependencies level. Thanks.

Comment: The Spring Boot Gradle plugin adds additional configuration to a projects build to allow building artifacts such as WAR and more. The Micronaut plugin does not offer such capability and as a result, you must make the changes yourself. You can raise a [feature request](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gradle-plugin/issues/new/choose) with the Micronaut team to see if such a capability is needed.

Comment: "The Spring Boot Gradle plugin adds additional configuration to a projects build to allow building artifacts such as WAR and more. The Micronaut plugin does not offer such capability and as a result, you must make the changes yourself." - Is there additional configuration that you would like added by default which is not included at https://micronaut.io/launch?type=DEFAULT&name=demo&package=com.example&javaVersion=JDK_11&lang=JAVA&build=GRADLE&test=JUNIT&features=jetty-server&version=3.2.0&activity=preview&showing=/build.gradle?